# What is "phone call" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I know that "to call someone on the phone" is "telefoni iun/al iu" but there is also the more general "alvoki". I'm having trouble making a noun out of the first verb, and I think I've heard "alvoko". ReVo gives me "voko" for "call". Is any of those right? Is there a different one?

Answer (score 8):

Claude Piron uzas la vorton *telefonalvoko* en sia libro „Ĉu li venis trakosme?“ Jen kelkaj ekstraktoj:

> *El tio rezultis, la sekvantan tagon, **telefonalvoko** al la episkopejo.*
>
> *Se okazus **telefonalvoko** aŭ vizito, mi devas povi kalkuli je vi!*